# iOS Swift Getting Approximate Location Indoors with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

For an app I am making I track the users location on a map. When outdoors, I am able to get the coordinates of the users position almost instantly and the app works great. Indoors, as expected, does not have GPS signal so I cannot get the location. That said, iOS uses Wifi and various other techniques to show my approximate location on a MapView still. However, I am unable to get the approximate coordinate while indoors even though iOS knows it (ie. didUpdateLocations is never called while indoors but is the second I walk out the door). I'm wondering if there is a way to get an approximate coordinate while indoors (I don't need exact).

Comment: Can you show your code?  Under what conditions are you looking for a location update?  As the user moves around indoors?  When the first go from outside to inside?  When your app is launched?  I just ran a quick test and launching my app indoors gives me a location update immediately

Comment: Nothing particularly special about the code. After calling locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() it starts getting the user's location for various reasons and works great outside but in a building I never get a coordinate (but as aforementioned it does show the location on a map). The conditions don't matter. If I use the app outside, I get coordinates and if I use it inside I do not at all.

Comment: As I said, a simple test app I created works both indoors and out.  You are doing something wrong, but if you won't show your code, we can't help.